# Filter multiple badges in a bootsrap-table column

Tags: javascript, html, filter, bootstrap-table, data-filtering

I have a table made with bootstrap-table and I have a column "status" in which a cell can contains multiple html badges.

I have a select data-filter-control but it doesn't work correctly.
The first problem was that I had html content in filter selection like this:

[image]

I resolved the first problem by add a data-filter-data-collector like this :

`<th data-field="status" data-filter-control="select" data-align="center" data-filter-data-collector="tableFilterStripHtml">Status</th>`

Here the js code for tableFilterStripHtml:

```
window.tableFilterStripHtml = function (value) {
    return value.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').trim();
}
```

Now the filter still doesn't work correctly. The problem is that I have same data in multiple rows selection of the filter. And for one row I should have one data, not multiple.
See this:

[image]

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution by myself, here the js code :

```js
window.tableFilterStripHtml = function (value) {
    var badges = value.match(/<span[^>]*>(.*?)<\/span>/g) || [];
    return badges.map(function (badge) {
        return badge.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '').trim();
    });
};
```